# MongoDB update to remove elements with just a timestamp field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've got a document which looks like this:

```javascript
{
    "events": [
        {
            "timestamp": ISODate("2015-12-08T13:35:40.797Z") 
        },
        {
            "timestamp": ISODate("2015-12-08T13:36:40.753Z"),
            "type" : "StatusSetEvent" 
        },
        {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-12-09T10:38:34.551Z")
        },
        {
            "status" : "in_progress",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-01-15T10:49:23.037Z"),
            "type" : "StatusSetEvent"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove all events from this document which has just `timestamp` field.
I tried with

```javascript
db.collection.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { events:
      { $elemMatch:
          { timestamp: { $gte : new ISODate("2012-01-12T20:15:31Z") } }
      }
  }
  },
  { 
    multi: true, 
  }
)
```

unfortunately with no luck:( I also tried to use `$date`, `new Date` - still no effect. Without `$elemMatch` it removes all the events which is not what I want.

I want to remove just the first and third element (only elements with `timestamp` field).

Comment: I want to remove just the first and third element (only elements with timestamp field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're targeting the wrong field in your query if you want to determine which elements are missing the other fields.

Instead of `$pull` querying against `timestamp`, it should check that whatever other field(s) the element requires is missing.

```js
db.collection.update(
  { },
  // Remove all elements that are missing a "type" field
  { $pull: { events: { type: {$exists: false } } } },
  { 
    multi: true, 
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. According to [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) `$elemMatch` is still not clear to me

Comment: @ambi You only need `$elemMatch` when you have more than one condition to check per element.

Comment: try to create survey collection with two documents just like in above docs. What should happen after `db.survey.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { results: { $elemMatch: { score: 4 , item: "B" } } } },
  { multi: true }
)` ? My understanding is that it should remove this element from `results` array which doesn't work

Comment: @ambi Go ahead and post that as a new question.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Data Types in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) both should be equivalent:

> The mongo shell provides various methods to return the date, either as a string or as a Date object:
>
> - Date() method which returns the current date as a string.
> - new Date() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.
> - ISODate() constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper.

Based on this, you should change this line:

```
{ timestamp: { $gte : new ISODate("2012-01-12T20:15:31Z") } }
```

to this:

```
{ timestamp: { $gte : ISODate("2012-01-12T20:15:31Z") } }
```